# Find most unique words, penalizing words in common

Tags: algorithm, search, ranking

suppose I have n classes like:

A:   this,is,a,test,of,the,salmon,system

B: i,like,to,test,the,flounder,system

C: to,test,a,salmon,is,like,to,test,the,iodine,system

I want to get the most unique words for each class, so something with a ranking that gives me

A: salmon

B: flounder

C: iodine, salmon

(as their first elements ; it can be a ranking of all words)

How do I do this? There will be hundreds of input classes each with tens of thousands of tokens.

I'm guessing this is essentially the sort of thing any search engine back-end does, but I'd like a fairly simple standalone thing.

Comment: Unless you are determined to write your own algo, you can do this with sentiment analysis or other text mining packages. Are you familiar with `R`?

Comment: You'll have to go through all words, create a dictionary and keep a count for each word. Then sort each class by the word count. Not a lot of options for an algorithm really...

Comment: Yeah, I can deal with R. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should have a look at TFIDF(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TFIDF). It picks the most frequent words but gives lesser weight to words which are common to all the documents. 
In general way, documents are represented in this form. 
This is in reference to the search engine example which u gave.

Comment: How are you defining a word as most unique?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to optimise -- but in an any case, "of" appears just once in the input, which is less frequently than "salmon", so why doesn't it appear anywhere in the output when the latter does?

Answer (score 2):

Using a language like Python, you can write this efficiently in 8 lines. For hundreds of groups, each with tens of thousands of tokens, the running time sounds like it will take at most a few minutes (although I haven't tried this on actual input).

1. Create a hash-based dictionary mapping each word to the number of its occurrences.
2. Iterate over all groups, and all words in a group, and update this dictionary.
3. For each group,

   a. If you need a total ranking, sort with the value in the dictionary as the critera

   b. If you need the top *k*, use an [order statistics type of algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) again using the value in the dictionary as the criteria

Steps 1 + 2 should have expected linear complexity in the total number of words.

Step 3 is *n log(n)* per group for total ranking, and linear in the total number of words otherwise.

Here is the Python code for the top *k*. Assume `all_groups` is a list of lists of strings, and that `k = 10`.

```
from collections import Counter
import heapq
import operator

c = Counter()
for g in all_groups:
    c.update(g)

for g in all_groups:
    print heapq.nsmallest(k, [(w, c[w]) for w in g], key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question, I come to this solution as the least used words per class comparing with all the other classes.

```js
var a = "this,is,a,test,of,the,salmon,system".split(","),
    b = "i,like,to,test,the,flounder,system".split(","),
    c = "to,test,a,salmon,is,like,to,test,the,iodine,system".split(","),
    map = {},
    min,
    key,
    parse = function(stringArr) {
      var length = stringArr.length,
          i,count;
      for (i = 0; i< length; i++) {
        if (count = map[stringArr[i]]) {
          map[stringArr[i]] = count + 1;
        }
        else {
          map[stringArr[i]] = 1;
        }
      }
    },
    get = function(stringArr) {
      min = Infinity;
      stringArr.forEach((item)=>{
        if (map[item] < min) {
          min = map[item];
          key = item
        }
      });
      console.log(key);
    };
parse(a);
parse(b);
parse(c);
get(a);
get(b);
get(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the classes, go through all the words and make a frequency table.

Then, for each class select the word with the lowest frequency.

Example in Python (slightly unpythonic solution to maintain readability for non-Python users):

```
a = "this,is,a,test,of,the,salmon,system".split(",")
b = "i,like,to,test,the,flounder,system".split(",")
c = "to,test,a,salmon,is,like,to,test,the,iodine,system".split(",")

freq = {}
for word in a + b + c:
    freq[word] = (freq[word] if word in freq else 0) + 1

print("a: ", min(a, key=lambda w: freq[w]))
print("b: ", min(b, key=lambda w: freq[w]))
print("c: ", min(c, key=lambda w: freq[w]))
```